# Как поставить background на рабочий стол телефона

Tags: android

Добрый вечер, возник вопрос:

Имеется программа с несколькими linearlayout у каждого стоит разный background из папки /res/drawable, по нажатию кнопки меняется layout и соответственно меняется backgroung на нем, вопрос в следующем , как определить какая картинка сейчас используется и поставить ее на рабочий стол телефона.
Как поставить картинку на рабочий стол из ресурса я представляю:

```
WallpaperManager wm = WallpaperManager.getInstance(this);
        try {
        wm.setResource(R.drawable.wallpaper3);
        } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
```

а вот как определить какая именно сейчас картинка на layout'e стоит затрудняюсь.
Я так понимаю что сначала надо определить ресурс каким либо образом, занести его в переменную, а потом использовать в WallpaperManager'e, но каким образом сделать это хз.

Притом если делать какие либо манипуляции с

`WallpaperManager.getInstance(this)`

он постоянно ругается на что то.

Даже наверное лучше вопрос поставить так, как получить параметр какого либо ресурса в переменную.
 потому как у нас в main.xml у linearlayout параметр android:background="@drawable/img1"
 или если использовать не linearlayout а например imageview у него будет параметр 
 android:src="@drawable/img1". В принципе если это узнать дальше можно будет разобраться, но примеры конечно же приветствуются :)

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как-нибудь так можно:

```
Drawable d = linearlayout.getBackground();
if (d instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
   BitmapDrawable bd = (BitmapDrawable) d;

   WallpaperManager wm = WallpaperManager.getInstance(this);
        try {
        wm.setBitmap(bd.getBitmap());
        } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: спасибо за ответ, работает.

А вот если мы используем ViewFlipper в нем есть несколько imageview, получается что мы делаем так 

 Drawable d = imgv.getDrawable();

Возможно ли сделать так чтобы в какую либо переменную заносились данные из imageview'a и потом использовать ее для получения картинки, типа так:

 Drawable d = <переменная>.getDrawable();

Т.е. по нажатию на кнопку мы считываем данные с imageview'a который сейчас на экране, притом какой именно imageview мы не знаем, или надо конкретно указывать по id ???